# Workday REST API - how to return additional fields

Tags: workday-api

I am very new to the Workday Rest API. We have a simple project where we need to update project time codes from another system for billing/time entry.

I am trying the basics of trying to get a list of projects. That works, but I only get a few fields returned in the results. How do I return additional fields? The community API explorer returns more fields. Things like the project hierarchy are present. In our sandbox, its just these basic fields.

Is this something in workday we need to get sorted out or do I need to pass in a parameter to the API call? Seems like such a basic thing but I am struggling to get past this.

Thank you!

[image: Postman sample results]